# Return PDF generated with FPDF in Flask

Tags: python, flask, fpdf

I can generate a PDF with an image using the code below.  How can I return the generated PDF from a Flask route?

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
img = input('enter file name')
g = img + '.jpg'
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(g, 50, 50)
pdf.output(img + '.pdf', 'F')
```

Answer (score 20):

Use [`make_response`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.make_response) to create a response with the PDF data output as a string ([`dest='S'`](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html)). [Encode the output as latin-1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35368352/400617), otherwise Flask will encode it as UTF-8 and it may not be valid.  Set the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` headers to tell the browser to download/handle a PDF file.  Return the constructed response.

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/jpg_to_pdf/<name>')
def jpg_to_pdf(name):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(os.path.join(app.instance_path, name + '.jpg'), 50, 50)
    response = make_response(pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'))
    response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=name + '.pdf')
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
    return response
```

This example assumes the images are in the instance folder, modify as necessary to point to where the images actually are.