# PyFPDF returning blank page - Python 2.7

Tags: python, flask, fpdf

I'm trying out the PyFPDF library in python 2.7 using Flask. I installed pyFPDF via pip. However, it's not returning a pdf, instead it it's just returning a blank page. I'm not receiving any errors. Am I missing something with the font? I'm just trying to use Arial. Here's my code:

```
@pdf.route('/pdf/<int:id>/pdf')
def pdf(id):

    id = str(id)

    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_xy(0, 0)
    pdf.set_font('arial', 'B', 13.0)
    pdf.cell(ln=0, h=5.0, align='L', w=0, txt="Hello" + id, border=0)
    return pdf.output('test.pdf', 'F')
```

Here's the link in my template which I'm using to trigger the PDF download;

```
<a href="{{ url_for('pdf.pdf', id=id) }}" class='btn pull-right margin-bottom'>
<i class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i> Export PDF
     </a>
```

The code above returns a blank page.

Comment: Possible answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157390/5781248

Comment: Thanks! This helped. With a bit of tweaking I was able to get it working based on the linked answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return PDF generated with FPDF in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149743/return-pdf-generated-with-fpdf-in-flask)